# Cant call key in multidimensional array (ReactJS)

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to access data.address.street but when I call data.address.street I  get a key undefined error.

when I call data.id, data.name, I have no problems but when trying to access the ones inside the multidimensional arrays(objects) I'm getting errors.

This is what I'm trying to call from:
 https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined
```

This is the complete data log:

```
address:
city: "Gwenborough"
geo: {lat: "-37.3159", lng: "81.1496"}
street: "Kulas Light"
suite: "Apt. 556"
zipcode: "92998-3874"
__proto__: Object
company:
bs: "harness real-time e-markets"
catchPhrase: "Multi-layered client-server neural-net"
name: "Romaguera-Crona"
__proto__: Object
email: "Sincere@april.biz"
id: 1
name: "Leanne Graham"
phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442"
username: "Bret"
website: "hildegard.org"
__proto__: Object
```

What logs when i call data.address:

```
Object
city: "Gwenborough"
geo: {lat: "-37.3159", lng: "81.1496"}
street: "Kulas Light"
suite: "Apt. 556"
zipcode: "92998-3874"
__proto__: Object
```

The code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default class UserPage extends React.Component{
    //https://www.taniarascia.com/using-react-router-spa/
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            value: '',
            loading: true
        };
        console.log(this.state)
    }

  // Using useEffect to retrieve data from an API (similar to componentDidMount in a class)
  useEffect = () => {
      // Pass our param (:id) to the API call
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }))
      .then(this.setState({loading: false}));
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.useEffect();
    }

  // Return a table with some data from the API.
  render(){
    const { data, value, loading } = this.state;
    console.log(data.address);
    return (
    loading ? (
    <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : (
    <div className="container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Website</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{data.id}</td>
            <td>{data.name}</td>
            <td>{data.username}</td>
            <td>{data.email}</td>
            **<td>{data.address.street}</td>**
            <td>{data.phone}</td>
            <td>{data.website}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  ))
  }
}
```

Comment: This not an appropriate use of `useEffect` hook. You should only use hooks in functional components.

Comment: What does `data` log?

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: But useEffect wouldn't be the problem I'm guessing, because that doesn't have much to do with showing data, it only fetches it, and seeing as I can use the other normal keys, I don't think that would be too big of a problem?

Comment: Right now it may not be the cause of the issue you're facing but that's not how you use hooks. You can just rename that to `fetchUser` and call it inside `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Alright thanks for letting me know that Ramesh.

Comment: @Daan, The data log is now in the post.

Comment: @Ramesh, the error is now in the post.

Comment: @Navycoder So `address` is empty? That explains why `data.address.street` doesn't work.

Comment: No, because if I console.log(data.address), I get the data from the API, I also posted this above to show you that there is data in Address. @Daan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mwwkvw?file=User.js) that fetches the user and displays the address, you can cross-verify your code with this.

```
import React from "react";

class User extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {},
    loading: true
  };

  fetchUser = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ user: res, loading: false })});
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, user } = this.state;
    console.log(user)
    return loading ? <div>Loading</div> : <div>{user.address.street}</div>;
  }
}

export default User;
```

**Update**

the problem is with the final `then` block in your function:

```
.then(this.setState({loading: false}));
```

should be

```
.then(() => this.setState({loading: false}));
```

or else you can just use single `then` block and modify the state inside it as I did in my stackblitz.

Comment: I have a file called HomePage.js where I am able to call this key and value, but this code is from the page UserPage.js and for some reason, here I cannot call keys from multidimensional arrays, I find it very weird why this would be a problem.

Comment: I have changed that line to .then(() => ..... ) but I am still getting the error @Ramesh, also it doesn't look like the change I made in that line changed nothing else in the project.

Comment: @Navycoder - You should definitely use the latter syntax. Make sure that `this.props.match.params.id` isn't changing to something that would result in an unexpected object. For example, if `this.props.match.params.id` is an empty string then you will get an array instead of a single object.

Comment: so what would be a good replacement for this.props.match.params.id?

Comment: You don't need to replace it. Just make sure you handle all the cases. Write an `if` statement so that you only fetch when  `this.props.match.params.id` is valid.